# UI Bug With Apache Airflow Tree View?

Tags: airflow

When I have a large number of tasks within a DAG or SUBDAG, I notice that the Airflow UI "TREE VIEW" does not display properly. Please see the attached image for an example.

I have attempted to view the airflow Tree View in both IE and Chrome, and I have tried zooming in / out, but the issue persists. Is this a known airflow bug? If so, are there any workarounds to it? I would think that the entire tree view could be displayed properly on the left, with the tasks on the right, even if I have to scroll. However, as you can see from the attachment, it is definitely NOT displaying properly.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMlHx.jpg

Comment: I have same issue. Interesting thing is that on Retina screen it looks fine - the dots are not overlapping the tree.

Comment: @tdg Did you figure this out? I am also having the same issue and as Konrad mentioned it looks fine on Retina screen.